# Better way to use SELECT WHERE in PHP for grouping similar values

Tags: php, mysql, select, gps, where-clause

I'm trying to group similar values within a 15 yard square (hence the specific values).

This is done by taking a latitude/longtitude value, subtracting or adding another value to/from it and if this condition is greater/less than the value, group

I've tried this using PHP by selecting the data from my mySQL DB using the following code:

```
$summarisedData = mysql_query("SELECT P_ID,COUNT(*) 
FROM road_awareness 
WHERE 
(
  (
     (
     LAT - '$value[LAT]' < (0.006858/69) 
     AND 
     LAT - '$value[LAT]' > (-0.006858/69)
     ) 
  OR 
     (
     LAT + '$value[LAT]' < (0.006858/69) 
     AND 
     LAT + '$value[LAT]' > (-0.006858/69) 
     )
   ) 
AND
 (
    (
    LON - '$value[LON]' < 0.006858/(cos($lat*M_PI/180)*69) 
    AND 
    LON - '$value[LON]' > -0.006858/(cos($lat*M_PI/180)*69)
    )
  OR 
    (
    LON + $value[LON]' < 0.006858/(cos($lat*M_PI/180)*69) 
    AND 
    LON + '$value[LON]' > -0.006858/(cos($lat*M_PI/180)*69)
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY LAT, LON");
```

This code is extremely hacky with lots of duplicate code and I'm not sure if it was correct. Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Am trying to make sense of the bracket grouping `;)`. You'll find it helpful to readability if you tweak the query layout so that sections are indented according to their bracket nesting, and it'll be easier for readers here too.

Comment: The bracket grouping made it pretty unreadable, hopefully this is an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it's better to precalculate some "sector" value (15 yard square each) on each record in `road_awareness` and than before query determine in which sector falls your $value[LAT]/$value[LON] and select by sector.

Comment: I used this plus followed more commands from mySQL to improve it, thanks!